# How to display Nested HashMap objects to a RecyclerView?

Tags: android, hashmap, android-recyclerview

I am having an using to trying to display data to a RecyclerView. Actually I want to display 3 different objects from different HashMap to a RecyclerView but if I kind of know how to do it with 1 it might get how to do it.

The way that the json is formatted I had to use HashMaps. Check it out
where you use see round colors that are the data I need

[image]

Now I don't know if I made the Modelclasses wrong but here are they down here and they work because I can get the right data to display on a log file I just dont know how to put it in a RecyclerView I removed some info in the Model class Movie class down here as you can see they are not important and would just make the page long.

```
public class Movie implements Parcelable {

@SerializedName("pid")
String movieId;

@SerializedName("idioma")
HashMap<String, MovieLanguage> movielanguages;

public Movie() {
}

public Movie(String movieId, HashMap<String, MovieLanguage> movielanguages) {
    this.movieId = movieId;

    this.movielanguages = movielanguages;
}


public String getMovieId() {
    return movieId;
}


public void setMovieId(String movieId) {
    this.movieId = movieId;
}




public HashMap<String, MovieLanguage> getMovieLanguage() {
    return movielanguages;
}
public void setMovieLanguage(HashMap<String, MovieLanguage> movielanguages) {
    this.movielanguages = movielanguages;
}
```

Another model class:

```
public class MovieLanguage implements Parcelable {


@SerializedName("formatos")
HashMap<String, MovieFormat> movieformats;


public HashMap<String, MovieFormat> getMovieFormat() {
    return movieformats;
}
public void setMovieFormat(HashMap<String, MovieFormat> movieformats) {
    this.movieformats = movieformats;
}
```

Here is another model class:

```
public class MovieFormat implements Parcelable {

@SerializedName("fechas")
HashMap<String, MovieDate> moviedates;


public HashMap<String, MovieDate> getMovieDate() {
    return moviedates;
}
public void setMovieDate(HashMap<String, MovieDate> moviedates) {
    this.moviedates = moviedates;
}
```

Here is the last model class:

```
public class MovieFunction implements Parcelable {


@SerializedName("session-status")
String functionStatus;
@SerializedName("session-time")
String functionTime;



public String getFunctionStatus() {
    return functionStatus;
}


public void setFunctionStatus(String functionStatus) {
    this.functionStatus = functionStatus;
}

public String getFunctionTime() {
    return functionTime;
}


public void setFunctionTime(String functionTime) {
    this.functionTime = functionTime;
}
```

Here is the code I use in a activity to get the log of the right info I need to display . I just need someone to point /help me in the right direction to display them in a RecyclerView.

```
for (Map.Entry<String, MovieLanguage> entry : mymovie.getMovieLanguage().entrySet()){
        HashMap<String, MovieFormat> movieformatw = entry.getValue().getMovieFormat();

        for (Map.Entry<String, MovieFormat> entry2 : movieformatw.entrySet()) {
            HashMap<String, MovieDate> moviedatesw = entry2.getValue().getMovieDate();


        Log.d("Header", entry.getKey()+ " " + entry2.getKey());


            for (Map.Entry<String, MovieDate> entry3 : moviedatesw.entrySet()){
                HashMap<String, MovieFunction> moviefunctionsw = entry3.getValue().getMovieFunction();

                if(entry3.getKey().contains(today)){
                    // checks if date is today and display data


                    for(Map.Entry<String, MovieFunction> entry4 : moviefunctionsw.entrySet()){



                        Log.d("movietimes ",  "" + entry4.getValue().getFunctionTime());


                    }


                }
                else{

                    // there are currently no movie for today do nothing

                }


            }

        }

    }
```

If I run the code above I get the following data what is right what I need to display in a RecyclerView also in the correct way

```
D/header: Subt Spanish DBOX-2D
D/movietimes:  7:00PM
D/movietimes:  9:30PM
D/movietimes:  4:30PM
D/movietimes:  2:00PM
D/header: Subtitulada DBOX-2D
D/movietimes:  7:00PM
D/movietimes:  9:30PM
D/movietimes:  4:30PM
D/movietimes:  2:00PM
D/header: DBOX DBOX-2D
D/movietimes:  7:00PM
D/movietimes:  9:30PM
D/movietimes:  4:30PM
D/movietimes:  2:00PM
```

Comment: May be this library is helpful for you. https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyListHeaders